# How to set topic level config while creating a new topic using node-rdkafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, librdkafka

I've been using node-rdkafka npm package for working with node and kafka.
For creating a new topic I've been using the following code:
`client.createTopic({ topic: topic.name, num_partitions: _.get(topic, "partitions", 1), replication_factor: _.get(topic, "replicas", 3) }`
I need to add topic level **retention.ms** for overriding the default 7 days set at the broker level. Is there any way to do this using node-rdkafka

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this.
There is a property 'config' of type object which can be used for this purpose:

```
client.createTopic({
    'topic': name,
    'num_partitions': partitions,
    'replication_factor': replicas,
    'config': {
        'retention.ms': '60000'
    }
}
```

This will set the **retention.ms** to 60000 ms. Note that all the key value pairs passed inside the 'config' parameter must be of type string.